# Twitter Typeahead : Display local data on focus for version 0.9.3

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to display the local data in suggestion dropdown when user focuses or clicks on input before user starts typing to fetch remote data. Here is my script.

```
$('.typehead').typeahead({
  name: 'names',
  remote: '/names?q=%QUERY',
  local: [{ name: 'x' }, { name: 'y' }, { name: 'z' }],
  valueKey: "name",
  template: function (data) {
    return '<p><i>' + data.name + '</i></p>';
  }
});
```

Comment: if the user types something, will local data be a part of the suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, Typehead should work the way it works with local data + remote.

Comment: I tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9gnj62L0/3/ It is buggy but maybe this can be helpful

Comment: if you use typeahead 1.10.x (i mean the latest), then it is easy to achieve it